# If sentence ignores equas() method to compare two strings

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, static

I am trying to compare the data from a jtable to a text field, but the if ignores it completely
I am using a static variable to compare

```
String ver = txtRefaccion.getText();

        boolean rev = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < this.Tabla.getRowCount(); i++) {
            Principal.Refrep = tblModel.getValueAt(i, 0).toString() + "\n";

            if (ver.equalsIgnoreCase(Principal.Refrep)) {
                rev = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        Principal.Refrep = "";
```

Comment: Try to use  , String ver = txtRefraccion.getText().toString();

Comment: No, it didn't work

Comment: Use Log to catch the two values before comparation and check the output to see what is wrong .